# No Boot Device Found on partitioned laptop after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 installed on my laptop. The other day Windows installed (on its own initiative) some upgrades. After that, turning on my laptop I realized that the usual dual-boot menu had disappeared and my laptop straightly booted Windows, without giving the option to access Ubuntu.
Since it seems this is a common problem, I found many advices on AskUbuntu site, and what I did was running as an administrator in Windows the following command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

I restarted and I couldn't access any more either to Ubuntu either to Windows!
I only get a black screen saying

```
No Boot Device Found. Press any key to reboot the machine.
```

Unfortunately, I'm not so expert of Ubuntu, so my first question is whether there is a way to undo the previous command.

What I did afterwards is to extract the hard disk in order to at least save some important documents (having no clue of the degree of the damage). Connecting the hard disk to a Ubuntu machine, I could retrieve my files (everything is there).
I also connected my hard disk to a Windows machine and checked that my Windows partition is also there with all my files.
Then I created a Ubuntu bootable USB stick and I've put my hard disk back into my laptop. With the Ubuntu bootable stick I was able to access my Ubuntu partition (using the option Try Ubuntu without installing).

Now I don't know what to do to recover both Ubuntu and Windows. I'm just afraid to do more damage by trying things without knowing what I'm doing.
Could anyone here help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What brand/model system? Some have unique requirements. Did Windows turn Secure Boot back on in UEFI? May be better to use `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` as shim is for secure boot. But with Secure boot on, you cannot dual boot from grub menu only from UEFI. If you want to remove the entry you have to use Windows bcdEdit program. See heynnema answer below and also post link to summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: It is a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Series - 7537. Eventually Boot-Repair did the job, here is the link to the summary report: http://paste2.org/kYe3L7LH

Comment: Looks like you should houseclean kernels. The newer ones should default to only 2 with `sudo apt autoremove`. Older ones from before an upgrade may not be in dpkg to auto remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `boot-repair` whilst booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. More info on how to use boot-repair can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  It was really simple and solved my problem,  now I can access both Ubuntu and Windows as before without having to reinstall anything.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your Ubuntu USB stick to do a reinstall, DO NOT format anything - install ubuntu onto itself, so everything is kept as it was. Now set Grub2 to install on SDA no number, and let grub find your Windows and create a boot option for that too. That should do it! I know there is a way of rescuing Grub, but I have not been lucky trying that so far.